# Debugging Realm in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, realm, ios8.3

I need to export .realm from Documents folder on real iOS device. Since iOS 8.3 Apple has disabled direct access to device's Documents folder how can I do that. For example I can send it by email, but is there any easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a device's container for your app from Xcode's "Devices" window with the following steps:

1. Connect your device to your Mac.
2. In the Devices window under Devices, select your device.
3. Under Installed Apps, select the app from the list.
4. From the Action menu (the gear icon), choose a menu item:

   - Show Container. A dialog shows the file contents of the container.
   - Download Container. In the dialog that appears, enter a location and click Save. The saved file will have a .xcappdata extension.
   - Replace Container. In the dialog that appears, select a file with a .xcappdata extension, and click Open.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/manage_containers.html

Answer (score 1):

You can still get to the Documents folder on a simulator.  To find the folder of the simulator you're running on, first type the following in Terminal:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

And note the UUID of the simulator you're currently using.

Then navigate to `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<Simulator UUID>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<Application UUID>/Documents/`.

You could also, in your app's code somewhere, get the path of your app's Document's folder and print it to the console with NSLog.  Then copy the path, switch to Finder and press Shift-Cmd-G.  Paste the path into the Finder field and it will take to your Documents folder.

Comment: I know that, but question is about seeing that data from real iPhone. iPhone records and processes data from real situations that cannot be simulated using Xcode Simulator.